# Else Value Inside Of PHP Copy Class

Tags: php, if-statement

What I am trying to accomplish, is for a file to be downloaded of one of two places. If the file doesn't exist it needs to try to download it from another location. However if the first file does exist, it needs to stop and not try to download the second file, otherwise the second file will still be downloaded as a blank file, overwriting the first one. How would I do this using something such as a else value?

```
<?php

$source_file = 'http://somesitehere.tld/' . $_GET["u"] . '.png'; 
$dest_file = '/enter/directory/here/' . $_GET["u"] . '.png';

copy($source_file, $dest_file);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using something like this, using either the **[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)**, **[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** or **[fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)** functions depending on your needs.

If you are using an internal file, try using **file_exists()**:

```
if( file_exists( $source_file ) ) { 

copy( $source_file, $dest_file );

} else {

copy( $source_file2, $dest_file2 );

}
```

And if you are using an external file try this using **file_get_contents()**:

```
if( file_get_contents( $source_file ) ) { 

copy( $source_file, $dest_file );

} else {

copy( $source_file2, $dest_file2 );

}
```

Alternatively you can try using **fopen()**:

```
if( fopen( $source_file ) ) { 

copy( $source_file, $dest_file );

} else {

copy( $source_file2, $dest_file2 );

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to grab internal or external files?

Comment: External, what I was trying to do myself was similar to the first one, which is probably why it wasn't working.

Comment: Your answer will be accepted in 5 minutes once it lets me actually press it.